# BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT doesnt compile on gcc 4.2 whereas it does on 3.4.6

Tags: c++, boost, gcc4

I am porting the project to compile with 4.2 compare to 3.4.6

I get the error while compiling following code in gcc 4.2 whereas it works fine in gcc3.4.6
error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE’

I tried using BOOST_MPL_ASSERT but wasn't successful.

```
template< uint64_t N , class T >
    struct count
    {
        BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( _to_bool_< typename _is_integer_<T>::value >::VALUE == true );
        //BOOST_MPL_ASSERT( ( bool_< _to_bool_< typename _is_integer_<T>::value >::VALUE == true > ) );

        static
        uint64_t compute( T const & p_arg ) {
            enum { VALUE = (  N >> 1 ),
                   MASK  = ( ( ( 1UL << VALUE ) - 1 )  ) } ;


            return   count < VALUE, T >::compute( MASK & ( p_arg >> VALUE ) )
                   + count < VALUE, T >::compute( p_arg & MASK  );
        }
    };
```

Lines of code causing error

```
if( count< static_cast< uint64_t >( 64 ), uint64_t >::compute( p_max_block_size ) > 1 ) {
                    set_fail_bit();
                    return 0;
                }
```

Comment: You need to show the full program, we don't know what `T` is and cannot test the code ourselves (Also gcc 3.4.6 is quite old).

Comment: I know 3.4.6 is old thats why I am trying to edit the project to make it build with 4.2; I have modified the question to show the line of code causing the issue.

Comment: I don't know what is `_is_integer_` or `_to_bool_`. Here is a minimal [test case](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4bXt1J$11) with `boost::is_integral` that works. Also, you shouldn't need `typename`  before `_is_integer_<T>::value` because it is a non-type.